# How to filter in ReactiveX too frequent onSubscribe requests

Tags: rx-java, rx-android

I have an observable that performs time consuming network operations. The client code might subscribe frequently to the observable which leads to a high network load.

Since we can't control when a subscriber appears this has to be done on the observable side.

Comment: When a subscriber is to be rejected do you want to push them an onError signal?

Comment: So you have an alternate observable that they will receive if there are too many subscribers?

Comment: Did you just want the subscriptions to be handled serially (one at a time?)

Comment: No I don't. I just wan't completely ignore such subscriptions. The easiest way to fix it is to store the last time subscription and if it is to frequent immediately call onComplete in the observable. But I would prefer rx way if any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the number of concurrent subscribers is at a maximum you want further subscribers to receive an empty stream.

Given a source that you want to limit subscriptions for, do this:

```
Observable<T> limited = source.compose(
        new TransformerLimitSubscribers<T>(
            new AtomicInteger(), maxSubscribers))
     .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.<T>empty());
...
limited.subscribe(s1);
...
limited.subscribe(s2);
```

where the transfomer is defined by this class:

```
public final class TransformerLimitSubscribers<T> implements Transformer<T, T> {

    private final AtomicInteger subscriberCount;
    private final int maxSubscribers;

    public TransformerLimitSubscribers(AtomicInteger subscriberCount, int maxSubscribers) {
        this.subscriberCount = subscriberCount;
        this.maxSubscribers = maxSubscribers;
    }

    @Override
    public Observable<T> call(Observable<T> o) {
        return o.doOnSubscribe(onSubscribe()).doOnUnsubscribe(onUnsubscribe());
    }

    private Action0 onSubscribe() {
        return new Action0() {

            @Override
            public void call() {
                if (subscriberCount.incrementAndGet() > maxSubscribers)
                    throw new TooManySubscribersException();
            }
        };
    }

    private Action0 onUnsubscribe() {
        return new Action0() {

            @Override
            public void call() {
                subscriberCount.decrementAndGet();
            }
        };
    }

    public static class TooManySubscribersException extends RuntimeException {
    }

}
```

Comment: updated the answer with desired return of empty observable. If you want to reject a new subscriber within a period after a successful subscriber has finished I suppose you could schedule the subscriberCount.decrementAndGet() to occur after a delay.

Comment: Compose is what I was looking for. I just changed your code a bit to disable subscription by time.